# what exactly does clojure-jack-in do? And how to config the settings with slime?

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime

what exactly does clojure-jack-in do? And how to config the settings with slime ?
What do I need to add to .emacs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`clojure-jack-in` starts a SLIME session for your current project.

It does this by generating a random port number, running `lein jack-in` with this port number in a sub-process, waiting for the swank server to start and then calling `slime-connect` with the port number.

Since `lein jack-in` is used to start the swank server, you obviously need to use Leiningen in your project and you need to have the swank-clojure plugin for Leiningen installed, either by installing it as a stand-alone plugin (`lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.2`), or by including it as a dev-dependency in your `project.clj`.

On the Emacs side, you need to install `clojure-mode`, preferably from [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/). You shouldn't need to add anything to your `.emacs`.

The difference between using `lein jack-in` (via `M-x clojure-jack-in`) vs. running `lein swank` is that `clojure-jack-in` also loads a version of SLIME that is bundled with the swank-clojure Leiningen plugin instead of the SLIME version installed in Emacs. I'm not sure what's the reasoning behind this, presumably just to make sure the SLIME version is compatible with the swank server.

Comment: The other reason is that the version of SLIME used with swank-clojure doesn't work properly with most Common Lisp implementations and is stripped of some of its features.

Comment: Do you know why these features were stripped? I never really ran into problems with the standard SLIME version and swank-clojure, now I use clojure-jack-in mostly for convenience.

Comment: I remember some cross referencing commands were missing, not everything from slime-fancy was there as well. At some point fuzzy-completion was missing, but I think it's has been added since than. Haven't used Clojure in a while and my memories are a bit vague. Slime's param highlight is not implemented as well I think.

Comment: Starting swank server...
ad-handle-definition: `slime-note.message' got redefined
Connecting to Swank on port 64608.. [2 times]
Versions differ: 2011-08-26 (slime) vs. 20100404 (swank). Continue? (y or n) 
Connected. Let the hacking commence!
Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer

if: Not connected. Use `M-x slime' to start a Lisp.

Comment: @ChristianBerg It's not about stripped features, it's about swank-clojure targeting ancient versions of SLIME that no other backend uses, period.